# ¿Cómo saber el lugar de un elemento (string) en un arraylist pero que está imprimiendo en forma aleatoria?

Tags: java, arraylist, random

quisiera saber si me podrían ayudar a saber cómo sé el lugar de un elemento string en un arraylist pero este array se está imprimiendo en forma aleatoria.

mi codigo lo tengo así

```
private static Random r = new Random();

     private String getRandomItem(List<String> pa){
         int i = r.nextInt(pa.size());
         salida.setText(pa.get(i));
         return null;   
     }
```

y dentro de un Jbutton de una interfaz gráfica tengo lo siguiente

```
private void btnsiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

        ArrayList<String> p = new ArrayList<>();

        p.add("brócoli");
        p.add("círculo");
        p.add("célula");
        p.add("carátula");
        p.add("depósito");
        p.add("física");
        p.add("ábaco");
        p.add("éter");

        getRandomItem(p);
}
```

Y me imprime los elementos aleatorios.

Yo lo que quiero es que cuando el botón sea presionado diga que está bien y o que está mal pero para eso necesito saber cuál es la posición de cada palabra en la lista.

O en otro caso una manera de poder ponerle posición a cada String con un arraylist.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, pero cuando haces Add en un array list se van añadiendo los elementos uno detras de otro, es decir brocoli seria la posicion 0,circulo la 1...

Comment: Detalla mas tu pregunta ya que es un poco confusa.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A tu pregunta le falta más información y quizás le sobra un poco de código. En qué momento preciso quieres saber la posición. Date cuenta que hay un momento ya dentro de tu programa en que la _sabes_, pero la dejas escapar. ¿cuál es la idea detrás de tu pregunta? o ¿para qué necesitas ese dato?. Lee el artículo y luego edita tu pregunta para mejorar tus probabilidades de obtener buenas respuestas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesito es sacar un elemento del arraylist para hacer una condición con un if.
Tengo dos botones uno con "Sí" y otro con "No" y una pregunta... "¿Está bien esta palabra?"
Al momento de darle que sí a esa palabra del array decir que sí o que no y que me muestre un mensaje que diga que está correcto o que no está correcto pero, ¿cómo sabe java qué palabra es o qué elemento de la lista es?